# What are Connes and co. talking about 'field with one element'?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What are Connes and coworkers talking about: [Fun with a field with one element](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=az_0pxm1jrI)? Also, http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.2401v1.pdf

I don't have much algebra background but thought a field with 1=0 is degenerate?

Comment: See [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2300/what-is-the-field-with-one-element), or in fact [all of these MO questions](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged?tagnames=f-1&sort=votes&pagesize=50).

Comment: Sometimes it is pretty clear that they make up stuff just to throw people off.